# In which position does Datomic lies in the CAP Triangle?

Tags: datomic

Recently I heard that Datomic as a modern database, can be excellent at data modeling and scalability. But I know little of it. Does the Datomic database follows the CAP Theorem?

If so, in which position does it lies in the CAP Triangle?

[image]

Comment: You may want to read: https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html

Comment: Excellent article! Thanks for that. @ValentinWaeselynck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Datomic provides ACID semantics and is CP for writes. The unusual thing about Datomic is that it does not co-locate read services with
transactional services. You don’t go through the transactor
to read and you don’t need to read inside transactions to
see consistent data. This allows Datomic to scale reads horizontally, and lets you make independent decisions about read availability.

It is worth reading http://docs.datomic.com/acid.html, particularly
the Implications section.

Comment: Stu, I think this deserves a more detailed answer than 'CP for writes'. Maybe add a more detailed explanation of why Datomic doesn't exactly fit CAP's hypothetical definition of a database system, and an description of how a Datomic system *as a whole* can avoid consistency violations (Phantom Reads, Stale Reads, Dirty Reads etc.) using e.g `conn.sync()`. I'd gladly give it a try myself, but it'd be more authoritative coming from the authors :)

Comment: Surely Datomic avoids these consistency violations by having a single writer (and is therefore automatically linearizable) ? From my understanding `conn.sync()` really just addresses stale reads, and only in the case where you read from a different peer to the one the newer write was written to. (Since that peer would have the write)

Comment: Actually after reading up more on linearizability, I'd say Datomic by default has sequential consistency. To be linearizable as a whole would require that every peer always sees the result of every transaction immediately after it is written. I think this is achievable with `conn.sync()` at the cost of additional latency.

Comment: O.Powell, to be clear here, peers are sequentially consistent but the transactor views the world as strictly serializable. Wanted to confirm if that matches up with your understanding. Also I'm curious if datomic cloud changes these consistency models. Ref for terms: https://jepsen.io/consistency/models/linearizable